# Simple polymer element is not rendering

Tags: html, cordova, mobile, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have trouble with Polymer. I wanna use it in my PhoneGap project, but on the start, I met a problem. The simple paper-button is not rendering. Even in a browser, not only on device. I will grateful for the help and for some tutorials about using polymer.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="import"  href="bower_components/polymer/polymer-mini.html">
    <link rel="import"  href="bower_components/paper-button">

    </head>
    <body>

    <p>Hello World!!!</p>
    <paper-button>GO</paper-button>




    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you get any error message in the browsers dev console?

Comment: Is the file being served through HTTP by a webserver or loaded as a file in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

The import of your `paper-button` is incorrect, you should use:

```
<link rel="import"  href="bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
```

Comment: did you try with webcomponents-lite.js and standard polymer.html ?

Comment: Yes, what the difference between webcomponents-lite.js and webcomponents.js . I tried. But it doesn't work.